# Remove accented characters form string - Python

Tags: python, unicode

I get some data from a webpage and read it like this in python

```
origional_doc = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

Sometimes this url has characters such as `é and ä and ect.`, how could I remove these characters, from the string, right now this is what I am trying,

```
import unicodedata
origional_doc = ''.join((c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', origional_doc) if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn'))
```

But I get an error

```
TypeError: must be unicode, not str
```

Comment: Is `origional_doc` a byte string or an unicode string?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It will eliminate all characters that are not ascii.

```
    original_doc = (original_doc.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii','ignore'))
```

Comment: what will it replace them with

Comment: As I said it would eliminate them, therefore it would replace them with nothing. If you want to replace them with something specific use original_doc = original_doc("é", "e")

Answer (score -1):

using `re` you can sub all characters that are in a certain hexadecimal ascii range.

```
>>> re.sub('[\x80-\xFF]','','é and ä and ect')
' and  and ect'
```

You can also do the inverse and sub anything thats NOT in the basic 128 characters:

```
>>> re.sub('[^\x00-\x7F]','','é and ä and ect')
' and  and ect'
```

Comment: could you show an example with a string, and I use 'ect' to mean etcetera, I want it to replace all these will there closest equilivent

Comment: I know you did, I just copied the text from your question. and this is a string so I dont know what you mean by show an example with a string

Comment: in terms of replacing them with their non-accented equivalent (which, might I add, strays from your original question) check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string)