# Python - replace accented characters with non accent

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I am parsing some HTML and sometimes I get some characters like `é` when I read the data, `doc = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()`, how can I find and replace these characters with there non accent equivalent?

The variable `doc` is a byte string, I have tried to convert it to unicode string like this

```
doc = doc.encode('utf-8')
doc = strip_accents(doc)
doc = doc.decode('utf-8')
```

Where `strip_accents` is

```
def strip_accents(s):
    return ''.join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s) if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn')
```

From this question [What is the best way to remove accents in a Python unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string)

But I get error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 161: ordinal not in range(128)
```

When I try to encode `doc`

How can I change the accented to non accented characters?

Comment: That answer is still correct, but stop working with bytestrings instead of text.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams How can I do that? I pretty sure that `urllib2.urlopen(url).read()` returns a byte string/?

Comment: I recommend using something that knows what it's doing, such as Requests. Using `urllib2` implies that the programmer understands lower-level concepts and will handle them as required.

Comment: @I how does request help remove the accented characters, I just looked it up, it gives me the encoding so now can I just use what I have above now and replace the utf-8 encoding with what I know it is now?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: The `text` attribute gives you actual text, if possible.

Comment: It cannot be done on byte strings. You need to figure out the encoding used, and decode that byte string to unicode text. And also please **avoid asking the same question twice** → [Remove accented characters form string - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33948042/remove-accented-characters-form-string-python), and do not add tags to the title of your question.

Comment: @spenf10 This is clearly a duplicate of your previous question. If you wanted to clarify, you could **[edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33948042/edit)** your question.